# Send socket before closing

Tags: c#, sockets

I have this code:

```
public static List<Socket> samp = new List<Socket>();
```

Socket connection/etc in form load..

```
IPHostEntry host = null;
Socket sock;
host = Dns.GetHostEntry(sending ip..);

foreach (IPAddress address in host.AddressList)
{
    IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, 7777);
    sock = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream,  ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sock.Connect(ipe);
    if (sock.Connected)
    {
        sock.SendTo(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("App starts"), ipe);
        samp.Add(sock);
    }
}
```

In form closing:

```
if (samp.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Socket socket in samp)
    {
        socket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("App closing"));
        socket.Close();
    }
}
```

And i'm getting error:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'

Thanks in advance!

**P.S** looks like socket.Close() works, but socket.Send nope :(

Comment: Do you use any `using` blocks with the sockets elsewhere in the code?

Comment: Can you post other code where you use the sockets? Maybe you call `.Close` elsewhere?

Comment: Maybe read up on the [`Socket.Close`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wahsac9k(v=vs.110).aspx) method: "it is recommended that you call `Shutdown` before calling the `Close` method. This ensures that all data is sent and received on the connected socket before it is closed." and "If you need to call `Close` without first calling `Shutdown`, you can ..."

Comment: Oh yes.. I have two socket.close, than's guys :)